# Compare values in two lists and assign new value to index if entries match

Tags: list-manipulation

Assume I have two lists, for example the following:

```
list1 = {1, 2, 1, 3, 2};
list2 = {{1, a}, {3, c}, {2, b}};
```

I would like to compare each element of `list1` with the first column in `list2` and if there is a match, assign the element from column 2 of `list2` to the corresponding index in a third `list3`.

In this case, `list3` would looks like this:

`list3 = {a, b, a, c, b}`

I am rather new to Mathematica and I'm sure there is a function for exactly this, but I spent several hours with `Map`, `Thread` and similar functions and haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: Welcome to Mma SE. To get started: 1) take the [introductory tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking checkmark sign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What about the simple?

```
list1 /. Apply[Rule, list2, {1}]
```

> [image: list]

Comment: Worked flawlessly, thank you!

Comment: @mrkhlavkalash you're very welcome. Glad I was able to help :-)

Answer (score 11):

You can also use [`Lookup`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Lookup.html):

```
Lookup[Rule @@@ list2, list1]
```

> ```
> {a, b, a, c, b}
> ```

Comment: Happy new year!!!

Comment: For `list1 = {1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 5};`, where some entries do not have a lookup value: `Lookup[Rule @@@ list2, #, #] & /@ list1`.

Comment: Happy new year to you too @bmf.

Comment: Thank you @Syed.

Comment: @kglr On the doc page, there was nothing about `Lookup` being able to handle lists, only associations; so I wrote the `Association` version of the answer; and then your answer appeared. Later on I found that as a side note in the `Details` section. I hope the page can be updated.

Answer (score 10):

Using `SequenceReplace`:

```
SequenceReplace[list1, Join @@ Function[{x, y}, Thread[Rule[{{x}}, y]]] @@@ list2]
(*{a, b, a, c, b}*)
```

Comment: Very nice!!! 3 down and 7 remaining :-)

Comment: New year, new game of the ten ways to code something :-)

Answer (score 9):

another possibility (8 more left)

```
Last@Reap@Scan[Sow@First@Cases[list2, {#, x_} :> x] &, list1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`Scan` is useful function. It applies a function to each element in a list. So useful for doing same thing to each element of a list. But note that with `Scan` need to use `Sow` in order to accumulate the result. It does not do it automatically. That is why `Sow` and `Reap` are needed above.

**Update**

Here is version with Flatten to give same result as all the other answers. I do not like very long commands, so I broke the above into 2 lines

```
Reap@Scan[Sow@Cases[list2, {#, x_} :> x] &, list1];
Flatten@Last[%]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: (+1) with a very minor comment that you can do a last `Flatten`. The other 8 ways are left as an exercise to the interested reader :-)

Comment: @bmf  Yes, sure an extra `Flatten` to remove one of the `{` will be needed but I wanted to make sure it all fit on one line, and `Flatten` is a long command so I removed it :), it is still not as short as your solution ofcourse.

Answer (score 9):

This isn't so much an answer as an attempt at pedagogy. The most canonical answer here is the one from @bmf, but as it stands I fear the OP may not quite grok what's going on.

@mrkhlavkalash, you've asked the question in terms of columns and indices, but the key insight is to see that what you're asking for is the exact functionality provided by `ReplaceAll` (which is typically written using the syntactic sugar of `/.`. Here's an example of `ReplaceAll`:

```
{1, 2, 3, 1} /. {1 -> "A", 3 -> XYZ}
```

Result: `{"A", 2, XYZ, "A"}`

Hopefully, that shows clearly how it works. Notice the 2 didn't get replaced, because there was no rule for 2. Each occurrence of 1 was replaced with "A" and each occurrence of 3 was replaced with the raw symbol XYZ. Our rules are specified with `->` (which is just syntactic sugar for `Rule`.

So, in your case, what we want is to end up with this expression somehow:

```
{1, 2, 1, 3, 2} /. {1 -> a, 3 -> c, 2 -> b}
```

You're already using a variable to hold the target list, so we really just need

```
list1 /. {1 -> a, 3 -> c, 2 -> b}
```

How can we transform list2? Well, `{1,a}` is an expression with head List, and we want an expression with head Rule. There is a way to replace a head, and it's called Apply (and yet again, there is a syntac sugar-y form `@@`. So,

```
Rule @@ {1, a}
```

gives `1 -> a`, aka `Rule[1,a]`.

But we need to do this for all of the pairs in list2. This can be done with `MapApply` (aka `@@@`). So,

```
Rule @@@ list2
```

gives `{1 -> a, 3 -> c, 2 -> b}`. This is exactly what we need. Putting it together,

```
list1 /. Rule @@@ list2
```

which gives `{a, b, a, c, b}`.

Okay, I pulled a bit of sleight of hand, because @bmf actually offered

```
list1 /. Apply[Rule, list2, {1}]
```

I already discussed Apply, aka `@@`, but you can provide an optional argument to specify the level at which to do the Apply-ing, and that's what the `{1}` is doing there. We're applying Rule to every element at level 1, and only level 1, in list2.

It's often fun to see how many different ways something can be accomplished in Mathematica, so I offered something slightly different.

Comment: that's a wonderful explanation and kudos for taking the time to write it down!

Answer (score 8):

Here I have added two entries for which lookup is not present; these are included without change.

```
list1 = {1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 5};
list2 = {{1, a}, {3, c}, {2, b}};
```

From first principles:

```
If[Position[list2, #, {2}] == {}, #, 
   Extract[list2, First@Position[list2, #, {2}] + {0, 1}]] & /@ list1
```

OR

```
SubstitutionSystem[Rule @@@ list2, list1]
```

which is redundant and overkill.

---

Result:

> {a, b, a, c, b, 4, 5}

Answer (score 6):

Using dict/map also works. In Mathematica, it's `<| |>`

```
{{1, a}, {3, c}, {2, b}} //
Map[Apply[Rule]] //
Association //
Map //
# @ {1, 2, 1, 3, 2}&
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `ReplaceAt` (new in V 13.1)

```
list1 = {1, 2, 1, 3, 2};
list2 = {{1, a}, {3, c}, {2, b}};

ReplaceAt[list1, Rule @@@ list2, All]
```

{a, b, a, c, b}

Why would we use `ReplaceAt` instead of the simpler `ReplaceAll` ?

```
list1 /. Rule @@@ list2
```

{a, b, a, c, b}

Because we can easily restrict the replacement(s) using the usual position syntax:

```
ReplaceAt[list1, Rule @@@ list2, 2 ;; -2]
```

{1, b, a, c, 2}

```
ReplaceAt[list1, Rule @@@ list2, {{2}, {4}}]
```

{1, b, 1, c, 2}

Answer (score 3):

For the specific example given by the OP

```
FromLetterNumber[list1]

(* {a,b,a,c,b} *)
```

Just for fun:

```
FromLetterNumber[list1,#]&/@{"English",Greek","Cyrillic",
  "Arabic","Russian","Devanagari",
  "Polish"}

{{a,b,a,c,b},{{α,β,α,γ,β}},{а,б,а,в,б},
 {ا,ب,ا,ت,ب},{а,б,а,в,б},{अ,आ,अ,इ,आ},
 {a,ą,a,b,ą}}
```